Shading issues when using material displacement
In Blender 4.2 i have problem with strange shading on corners when using material displacemnt. After exporting this scene to blender 3.6 the problem disappear. Is it posible to solve it in blender 4.2 or is just a bug?


Looks like it could be due to the Bevel modifier. Try playing with settings in the Shading section of it.

I have added bevel to create support loop, there are there renders: 1)flat shading 2)smooth shading 3)smoth + support loops. Neither of them works well.

Two attempts: fiddle with the displecement x bump options in the material "settings" section. And mainly, try to change the "middle" value for the displacement, if the displacement goes "outwards", it stretches corners, but if it goes inwards, or at least not too much outwards, then the stretching can probably solve (if you could share the file it would be easier to point the solution)
